# Statement about rational approximations for $\pi$

Tags: number-theory

According to a result by Kurt Mahler, there is $q_0$ such that $\forall p, q \in \mathbb{Z}, q > q_0,$
$$\mid\frac{p}{q}- \pi\mid > q^{-42} $$

However, I have never been able to find a proof of this. Does anybody know where I can find a proof of this statement or any generalization of it?

Comment: What about $p = 3, q = 1$?

Comment: The original paper can be found [here.](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/collected.html) It is paper 119 in the list.

Comment: Mayank, I edited slightly to fix the typo that led to Christopher Wong's question. (The result is usually stated by saying that the inequality holds, except for finitely many exceptions, which is equivalent to the version with $q>q_0$ for some $q_0$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A paper of Hata, which improves on Mahler's result, is available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-68/issue-9/Improvement-in-the-irrationality-measures-of-pi--and-pi/10.3792/pjaa.68.283.full). Unless you are familiar with diophantine approximation techniques, you will not find it easy going.

There is some related discussion at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23547/does-pi-contain-1000-consecutive-zeroes-in-base-10).

Comment: Apparently improved to $7.6063$ in Salikhov, V. Kh. "On the Irrationality Measure of pi." Usp. Mat. Nauk 63, 163-164, 2008. English transl. in Russ. Math. Surv 63, 570-572, 2008.

Comment: Yes, that's noted at the MO link, I believe.

Comment: Aha, Wadim. He and I write sometimes.